# C# XML read and edit child value

Tags: c#, xml

**EDIT**

Problem solved, for those who need it, here's what I did

***Edited XML:***

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- DON'T EDIT THIS FILE!-->
<config>
  <DirectoryIndex value="False" />
  <FirstRun value="True" />
  <GamePath value="" />
  <Language value="English" />
</config>
```

***GET VALUES FROM XML:***

```
var XMLDoc = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "config.xml");

string DirectoryIndex = XMLDoc.Root.Element(XName.Get("DirectoryIndex")).Attribute("value").Value;
string GamePath = XMLDoc.Root.Element(XName.Get("GamePath")).Attribute("value").Value;
string Language = XMLDoc.Root.Element(XName.Get("Language")).Attribute("value").Value;
string FirstRun = XMLDoc.Root.Element(XName.Get("FirstRun")).Attribute("value").Value;
```

***EDIT AND SAVE THE VALUES:***

```
XMLDoc.Root.Element(XName.Get("DirectoryIndex")).Attribute("value").SetValue("NewValue");
XMLDoc.Root.Element(XName.Get("GamePath")).Attribute("value").SetValue("NewValue");
XMLDoc.Root.Element(XName.Get("Language")).Attribute("value").SetValue("NewValue");
XMLDoc.Root.Element(XName.Get("FirstRun")).Attribute("value").SetValue("NewValue");

XMLDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "config.xml");
```

---

> I've this XML file:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
> <!-- DON'T EDIT THIS FILE!-->
> <config>
>   <setting key="DirectoryIndex">
>     <value>False</value>
>   </setting>
>   <setting key="GamePath">
>     <value></value>
>   </setting>
>   <setting key="Language">
>     <value>English</value>
>   </setting>
>   <setting key="FirstRun">
>     <value>True</value>
>   </setting>
> </config>
> ```
>
> My application need to allocate in a string variables all values from
>   XML file.. example:
>
> ```
> string DirectoryIndex = "Instructions To Get "DirectoryIndex" value from XML file";
> string GamePath = "Instructions To Get "GamePath" value from XML file";
> string Language = "Instructions To Get "Language" value from XML file";
> string FirstRun= "Instructions To Get "FirstRun" value from XML file";
> ```
>
> Next, when all variables are allocated i need to edit the values in
>   XML file.. example:
>
> ```
> string NewValueForDirectoryIndex = "True";
> ```
>
> I would like this output:
>
> ```
> <setting key="DirectoryIndex">
>   <value>True</value> <!-- Obtained from "NewValueForDirectoryIndex" -->
> ```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for exactly, editing of XML values is easier is you use XElement,I cant give more feedback as I dont understand the question

Comment: The explanation of the question is rather convoluted. You can use XElement to build a IEnumerable XML to Linq structure, and simply call SetValue on a specific XElement.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for the answers.